# How to include jQuery and JavaScript files correctly?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm doing it right now with the following code:

```
function uw_load_scripts() {
    // De-register the built in jQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    // Register the CDN version
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false); 
    // Load it in your theme
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uw_load_scripts' );
```

This works, but should I do this for everyone, like this, or for everyone but admin (so that backend uses the WordPress version?):

```
if (function_exists('load_my_scripts')) {  
function load_my_scripts() {  
    if (!is_admin()) {  
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );  
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');   
    }  
}  
}  
add_action('init', 'load_my_scripts');
```

This version doesn't work at all actually, I get the WordPress jQuery-version and not the Google one.

Therefore, should I deregister the jQuery that is included in WordPress at all?

Also, how do I add my own scripts (slider scripts, modernizr and my own custom.js) the correct way? I guess I should do this via functions.php as well and not in the header like I'm doing it now, but I'm unsure of how I would do that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First rule of thumb: **do not deregister core-bundled scripts and replace with other versions**, unless you are absolutely certain that no Theme, Plugins, or core itself will break due to the version change. Really, unless you **absolutely need** an alternate version of a core-bundled script, just use what is bundled with core.

Second, I strongly recommend hooking into `wp_enqueue_scripts` for script registering and enqueueing, rather than `init`. (It *works* at `init`, but from a *play-nicely-with-others* perspective, it's best to use the most semantically correct hook.)

Third, to enqueue your own custom scripts, you use the same methods as above:

```
<?php
function wpse45437_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $script_path = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/';
        // Enqueue slider script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse45437_slider', $script_path . 'slider.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        // Enqueue modernizr script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse45437_modernizr', $script_path . 'modernizr.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse45437_enqueue_scripts' );
?>
```

Just add whatever scripts you need to enqueue.

Comment: +1 on the **absolutely need to**! Too many (usually 'premium') themes register an outdated version of jQuery. It breaks plug-ins.

Comment: Adding this script into my functions file (without the php declarations since they are already there) gives me a 'Http-error 500 (Internal server error)'.

Is there an error somewhere?

Comment: Yes; there was a syntax error in the `wp_enqueue_script()` calls.

Comment: Thanks now it works! However it is still outputted in the header. Is it not better if it where in the footer? If so, can I modify the code so it will?

Comment: You can certainly enqueue in the footer. Just set the `$in_footer` parameter to true in your call to [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: Chip, `is_admin` isn't necessary here, is it?

Comment: Perhaps it's overkill, but I *always* wrap front-end script enqueues in `if ( ! is_admin() )`, because `wp_enqueue_scripts` fires in both the front end *and* in the back end.

Comment: As per Pieter Goosen's [comment here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214417/43806) `is_admin()` is not necessary. This is a couple years old though so I'm not sure if things have changed.

Comment: What/Where are the core-bundled scripts in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps, look up the codex for [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more information.

1. Dont use `init` to **enqueue**. Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` for front-end stuff and `admin_enqueue_scripts` for admin side. You can use `init` to **register** scripts though.
2. The hook `wp_enqueue_scripts` only fires on the front-end (and not on the 
   log-in page) - so you don't have to check `is_admin()`.
3. Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, I would suggest registering and queuing scripts using `functions.php` for *themes* or in a plug-in otherwise. You simply put:

   ```
    function myprefix_load_scripts() {
      // Load scripts here
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_load_scripts' );
   ```
4. If the aim is to enqueue a script when a shortcode is used, you may wish to use `wp_enqueue_script` in the shortcode callback to queue it only when needed (this will print it in the footer **since 3.3**).
5. You shouldn't re-register the existing jQuery on the admin side. You may break something :D.
6. Plug-ins **should not** re-register the existing jQuery.
7. You should weigh up the pros and cons of re-registering jQuery. For instance it may break some plug-ins if you register an old version (maybe not now, but in the future...)

Comment: Ad 5) re-registering doesn't really matter. That's why we got the enqueue and register functions. :)

Answer (score 2):

Fair warning: deregistering WP's packaged version of jQuery in favor of your own can cause problems, especially if you aren't extra careful to make sure that you change the version you're pointing toward whenever WP updates its version. This goes doubly for plugins, which often (or often should, at least) write their plugins for maximum compatibility with the WP version of jQuery.

That said, your first version is correct - it's hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Your second function is hooked to `init`, which may be why it's not working properly.

Add your own scripts in a similar manner:

```
function bbg_enqueue_scripts() {
    // You should probably do some checking to see what page you're on, so that your
    // script only loads when it needs to
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bbg-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_url() . '/js/bbg-scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bbg_enqueue_scripts' );
```

I'm assuming here that you are loading scripts from a `js` directory in your current theme directory; change the URI parameter if that's not true. The third parameter `array( 'jquery' )` says that `bbg-scripts` depends on `jquery`, and so should be loaded afterward. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (function_exists('load_my_scripts')) {  
function load_my_scripts() {  
    if (!is_admin()) {  
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );  
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');   
    }  
}  
}  
add_action('init', 'load_my_scripts');
```

This isn't going to do anything... I suspect you mean

```
if (!function_exists('load_my_scripts')) {
```

Your example will only load the function load_my_scripts if it already exists (which it doesn't so it won't and if it did it would create an error)

Answer (score 0):

If, for performance reasons, you want to load jquery and other core js-files from a CDN, make sure you are loading the same version to prevent nasty things happening with core and plugin functions. Like this:

```
$wp_jquery_version = $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['jquery-core']->ver;
$jquery_version = ( $wp_jquery_version == '' ) ? '1.8.3' : $wp_jquery_version; // fallback, just in case 
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/'. $jquery_version .'/jquery.min.js', $jquery_version, false );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Answer (score -2):

After checking all different methods for loading jquery (not only on this post), I realized that none of them do all of these:

1. Register (and perhaps enqueue) jquery using a function , so it can be used by plugins.
2. Load it from Google CDN with protocol relative url.
3. Fallback to local copy if Google is offline.

There a lot of alternate versions doing some of these in the list, but not all, so I wrote my version combing and modifing some of the methods already available. Here it is:

```
function nautilus7_enqueue_scripts() {

    // Load jquery from Google CDN (protocol relative) with local fallback when not available
    if ( false === ( $url = get_transient('jquery_url') ) ) {

        // Check if Google CDN is working
        $url = ( is_ssl() ? 'https:' : 'http:' ) . '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
        $resp = wp_remote_head($url);

        // Load local jquery if Google down
        if ( is_wp_error($resp) || 200 != $resp['response']['code'] ) {

            $url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js';
        }

        // Cache the result for 5 minutes to save bandwidth
        set_transient('jquery_url', $url, 60*5);
    }

    // Deregister Wordpress' jquery and register theme's copy in the footer
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', $url, array(), null, true);

    // Load other theme scripts here

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nautilus7_enqueue_scripts');
```

In order to save bandwidth and not ping Google every time the page is reloaded it remembers whether Google CDN is online or not for 5 minutes using the Wordpress Transient API.

Comment: **Not recommended.** Now you have to update the script after each WordPress update to match the exact jQuery version WordPress is using. Plus, Google fails to send the library compressed in some cases, so your page is loading slower now.

Comment: I am not using wordpress' jquery. Read the code please. I am using the theme's version. And if you don't like google, you can use another cdn.

Comment: But that's the point: You should use the WordPress jQuery to make sure the version is correct.

Comment: I don't follow you. I grab whatever version I need from google and I bundle the same version with my theme. That's how everyone is doing it. Wordpress can use (in the admin section) whatever version it comes with.

Comment: Plugins using JavaScript in front-end rely on the correct version too.

Comment: So, your point is that we should never replace jquery that ships with Wordpress with another version. That's has some base behind it but I doubt if using another version has any real disadvantages. Anyway, I don't get why do you criticize my method? You could say you 're against replacing jquery in general in a separate answer to the original question. All methods-answers here have one purpose: replace the jquery file that comes with wordpress. I just made a better method to do it and you don't criticize my method at all.

Comment: See Chip's answer for the Why. And please – don't take votes personally.

Comment: It seems you don't get it... You are against doing one thing. This is replacing wordpress' jquery. That's your opinion and it is absolutely respected. But there are some people that want to do it and search for the best method for it. Do you have anything useful to say formy code? Why is it worse (if it is) than the other replacing codes?

Comment: You can use what ever version of jQuery you want but if you are bundling it with a theme you are forcing this on your users.  A few years from now when everyone is using jQuery 1.8.2 your users will be stuck on an outdated version unless they keep the theme up to date.

Comment: Are you going to make this comment to the others who proposed a method for replacing jquery as well, or just me? There are hundreds of threads here and all around the web. Start commenting there too. I don't see why I get all the comments...

Comment: I just found a plugin with jQuery 1.5 bundled and of course, it breaks the admin... -1 for the bad solution.