# Executing jQuery in a plugin

Tags: plugins

I have the following code in my plugin main file :

```
function my_function() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(function () {    
        alert('jQuery');
    });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action("wp_footer", "my_function");
```

My website does have jQuery loaded and operational (lots of features on my page use it and they work). Yet this alert() doesn't work. Why is that ?

Answer (score 2):

That snippet 'works' for me.

Is the script being printed at the bottom of the page? More specifically, does your theme call [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer). All themes should, but not all themes do call `wp_footer` which breaks plugins which rely on it.

For the record -  you should not print scripts directly to the page. WordPress has a great API for handling JavaScript enqueing and dependency handling. [See this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

You may also find [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/including-jquery-and-jquery-files-the-correct-way) helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Because you just defined a function there. You didn't execute it or attached it to some event, to be executed when the event happens.

You probably want:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  alert('jQuery');
});
```

Now this function will run after the document has loaded.

And try to avoid inline scripts. Use [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) whenever possible.