# Jquery is not working in wordpress php file

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to scroll the div content vertically.

I have used the following line of code in `function.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enquque_scripts', 'my_script_enqueue' );

function my_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery', '/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/js/jquery-1.9.0.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

then i have included a JS file in my PHP file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/dw_scroll_c.js"></script>
```

In that JS file I am just displaying as alert as follows:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    alert('hi');
});
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Please read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/including-jquery-and-jquery-files-the-correct-way

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery-1.9.0.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

check for jquery error also check with source code if file is being loaded or not.
you must have included jquery library before including your js file.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include js file in your php files, instead use the hook. below code will work for you. See the dependency parameter for `wp_enqueue_script` function. Your dw sroll file is dependent on jQuery.

```
add_action( 'wp_enquque_scripts', 'my_script_enqueue' );

function my_script_enqueue(){
wp_enqueue_script('dw_scroll_c','/js/dw_scroll_c.js',array( 'jquery' ));
}
```