# How can insert JQuery in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery

My question is how I can insert jquery libraries into Wordpress and how can I deal with them.

Thank you.

Comment: Download, register, enqueue, ... take a look at the "WP Dependency API" in Codex, please. Then file an [edit] and rephrase your question with a specific problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress gets delivered with jQuery. All you have to do is tell your theme to `wp_enqueue_script()` jQuery:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

This code belongs into your `functions.php`. Of course, you can also change which version of jQuery should be loaded, and from which ressource, check [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/including-jquery-and-javascript-files-the-correct-way) for further details.

Afterwards you can put your jQuery-magic into any javascript that is loaded within your theme.

Comment: Just remember that this loads jQuery in noConflict mode so the `$` shortcut won't be available. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers