# How to add plugin with jQuery to custom theme?

Tags: jquery

I need to add carousel slider in my theme. It requires jQuery and jQuery is build in WP core. How can I add carousel script using this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include jQuery and JavaScript files correctly?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/how-to-include-jquery-and-javascript-files-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

It should be said, that WordPress comes with jQuery out-of-the-box. You can check it, if you slap this in your page-template ([based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341865/checking-if-jquery-is-loaded-using-javascript)):

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
}
```

In case you need other scripts, then perhaps look into the [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)-function.

---

**Only load script on certain pages**

Based on your comment, then I thought I add a snippet you could try (from [this page](https://dobsondev.com/2015/06/05/conditionally-enqueue-stylesheet-into-wordpress-for-certain-page/)):

```
function custom_enqueue_scripts() {
  if ( is_page_template( 'page-template-name.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/YOUR_CUSTOM_SCRIPT.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts' );
```

As you can see, then the third parameter is `array( jquery )`, which is an array of dependencies. Which means that your script will not be loaded before that given script (jquery) has been loaded. Super-smart! :-)

---

**Load script on all pages**

This is if you want your script to load on all pages.

```
function custom_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/YOUR_CUSTOM_SCRIPT.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Ok. But can I add scripts with wp_enqueue_script function not in footer or header, but in body, right before script when jQuery is needed?

Comment: As far Is I know, then you shouldn't insert scripts in the body, as you propose. You should control which scripts are enqueued using wp_enqueue_script in the functions-file. If you want to only load a script on a certain page, then [this page](https://dobsondev.com/2015/06/05/conditionally-enqueue-stylesheet-into-wordpress-for-certain-page/) explains a bit about if. The cool thing about wp_enqueue_script is, that you can specify dependencies - and WordPress ensures that scripts aren't loaded twice.

Comment: I just added an example to my proposed solution.

Comment: Ok, but should I register my scripts first or not? (I'm not talking about jQuery byt my custom scripts).

Comment: If you put your script into a file and save it in `/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/assets/js/YOUR_CUSTOM_SCRIPT.js`, - then you can copy paste the snippet from my answer into your functions.php-file and then it should work (take the one that loads on all pages at first, to ensure that it works). You can test it by adding a `console.log('test');` to your script and see that it executes. I've modified my answer for this.

Comment: I found what I miss. In WP when I need use jQuery I need use scripts with compatibility mode, so I should use *jQuery* instead of *$*. Im looking now how can I change that :)

Comment: I see. Perhaps [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) can help you there.