# How register library to use jquery correct

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

How register from my plugin level correct jquery?

If i run this :

```
 function insertJQuery() {

               wp_deregister_script('jquery');
               wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);

     }

  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'insertJQuery');
```

And this work, but if i run this:

```
    function theme_scripts() {
              wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

Then scripts in site not work. I read to use the jquery version installed in WP. How do you finally use it correctly to be safe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include jQuery and JavaScript files correctly?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/how-to-include-jquery-and-javascript-files-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the built-in version of jQuery for compatibility reasons.

All you need to do is to enqueue it:

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

Or just add it as a dependency for your script:

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', <PATH>, array('jquery'), ... );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

**But then...** you have to remember, that jQuery is run in no-conflict mode, so in your scripts you have to access it by `jQuery` and not by `$`. So your script should look like so:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // here you can use $ sign to get jQuery, because of the param of function

    $('a').click(...); // so this will work OK
});

// but here you can't and you have to use jQuery
jQuery('a').click(...); // this will work also

$('a').click(...); // but this won't, because there is no $ accessible here
```